# How to add a font to linux that can be used by pango

Tags: linux, fonts

I am trying to use the default built-in terminal font with Sakura(which by looking at the source I can tell uses pango for its fonts). However, when I execute pango-list I get alot less results than fc-list and xlsfonts(which both have "fixed" in their output), and in particular missing the one I am looking for called "Fixed".

I have checked /etc/default/console-setup and there it is just called "Fixed".

[Here is a picture of the font I'm talking about](https://prnt.sc/p1uw74)

Comment: Related https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/issues/386 ?